# cross-database references are not implemented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to run the SQL query but I am receiving "cross-database references are not implemented". This is the query:

```
scope :new_registration_having_validation_documents, lambda {
    where(%{
      NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
          FROM assigned_roles
          JOIN roles ON assigned_roles.role_id = roles.id
          WHERE assigned_roles.user_id = #{quoted_table_name}.id
           AND roles.validation_required
           AND NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT NULL
                FROM user_validations
                JOIN validation_templates ON validation_templates.id = user_validations.validation_template_id
               WHERE user_validations.assigned_role_id = assigned_roles.id
                AND user_validations.validation_template_id IS NOT NULL
                AND assigned_roles.user_validations_count < assigned_roles.role.validation_templates.count
                OR validation_templates.notary_form = false AND #{quoted_table_name}.identity_quiz_passed = true))
          })
  }
```

The error populates on Jenkin's pipeline like this:

```
[2022-08-12T07:05:55.550Z]      ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:

[2022-08-12T07:05:55.550Z]        PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: assigned_roles.role.validation_templates.count

[2022-08-12T07:05:55.550Z]        LINE 14: ...      AND assigned_roles.user_validations_count < assigned_r...

[2022-08-12T07:05:55.550Z]                                                                      ^
```

helpful reference: The activerecord method that is responsible for this is:

```rb
def all_documents_uploaded?
    roles_requiring_upload_validation_docs.each do |assigned_role|
      return false if assigned_role.user_validations_count < assigned_role.role.validation_templates.count
    end
    true
  end
```

UPDATE: The issue is that in assigned_roles.role.validation_templates.count working from right to left you have column(count), table(validation_templates), schema(role) and then database(assigned_roles). Postgres does not allow cross database references so assigned_role(assuming this is even a database name) is the problem.

Comment: `assigned_roles.role.validation_templates.count` is the culprit. Did you mean `assigned_roles.role.validation_templates_count`

Comment: I don't have any validation_templates_count. The relationship between "role" and "validation_template" is one_to_many relationship. Basically, I want to count how many validation_templates do i have within assigned_roles.role

Comment: Should I possibly try just roles.validation_templates.count?

Comment: The issue is that in `assigned_roles.role.validation_templates.count` working from right to left you have column(`count`), table(`validation_templates`), schema(`role`) and then database(`assigned_roles`). Postgres does not allow cross database references so `assigned_role`(assuming this is even a database name) is the problem.  Are you actually trying to reach another database in the cluster? **Add answer as update to question**.

Comment: Per my previous request add the information to the question properly formatted.

Comment: I have no clue about ActiveRecord, but I'm going to go with @a_horse_with_no_name and say this `assigned_role.user_validations_count < assigned_role.role.validation_templates.count` should be `assigned_role.user_validations_count < assigned_role.role.validation_templates_count`. Or you need to do `count(role.validation_templates)` somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the "assigned_roles.role.validation_templates.count" . The cross-database references are not possible in the postgresql directly, there are some extensions which needs to be implemented like - "postgres_fdw" for accessing the different database from the one database.